python and sparse matrix made out of 2X2 matrices
I can straight forwardly create the matrix C as (where the elements 0, A, B are 2X2 matrices)
[ 0 A 0 0 0 0 ...       0 0 
  B 0 A 0 0 0 ...       0 0
  0 B 0 A 0 0 ...       0 0
  0 0 B 0 A 0 ....      0 0
            ..........
  0 0 0 0 0   ....      B 0]

where 0 is the 2X2 matrix consisting of zeros, A, B are given 2X2 matrices (that are to be placed along the upper and lower diagonals respectively) and the matrix C is of size 2JX2J
However, it occurred to me that it is probably more efficient to directly make use of sparse matrix notation and then set the non-zero elements using something like (with J = 5)
def TheMatrix(J,alpha):
A = [[0.5, alpha],[ alpha,0.5]]
B =[[0.5,-alpha],[-alpha,0.5]]

upperDiag = A*np.ones(J-1)
lowerDiag = B*np.ones(J-1)

diagonals = [upperDiag, lowerDiag]  # non-zero diagonals
ASparse = sps.diags(diagonals,offsets=[1, -1])
ASparse = sps.csc_matrix(ASparse)

However, this does not seem to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed? In detail, the error reported (for the case J =5) is
File "myprg.py", line 16, in TheMatrix(J,alpha)
upperDiag = A*np.ones(J-1)
            ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (5,)

So, I understand that the need is to somehow replace np.ones(J-1) to something that makes it compatible with A, B being 2X2 matrices and not scalars.

What exactly is not working?  Could you post your error and what you expect the output to be?  Your example works for me.  If you want the full matrix, you can use ASparse.toarray().

I don't think diags will help. Look at the documented example.  There is a block csr format, bsr. It's not heavily documented. In the past when I created FE stiffness matrices, I constructed COO inputs - which allows for overlapping blocks.

Roughly what's J?  Are there only 3 2x2 blocks, A, B, 0?

bsr is the only format that preserves the component arrays.  There are a number of utilities that can make an array/matrix from blocks (vstack, block_array, block_diag etc) but they all use the same idea - combine the component COO attributes into a single set, and make the joint COO from that.

I include the following in case it helps others: To create the sparse matrix I took up the comments from delfstack
Because a sparse matrix is a list of the positions and values of the non-zero elements, it is straight forward to accept that the sparse matrix can be formed from this information and delfstack shows how this works with the input matrix "Ain"
Ain = np.array([[16, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0]])

delfstack suggests
Asparse = []                   # initialise Asparse to the empty element
rows, cols = Ain.shape         # the input matrix
for i in range(rows):
for j in range(cols):
    if Ain[i][j] != 0:         # identify the non-zero elements 
        triplet = [i, j, Ain[i][j]]
        Asparse.append(triplet) # append to update Asparse

(In my example I don't actually create the matrix A).
This seemed to mostly work, however I did hit an unexpected issue when I started to check my result by reconstructing the original matrix. This threw me until I started printing out data. When I printed out a particular triplet, it gave the result
triplet =  [0, 0, np.int64(16)]

and there were problems adding np.int64(16) to 0. To overcome this I had to make the minor change
        triplet = [i, j, Ain[i][j]]
        triplet = list(map(int,triplet))
        Asparse.append(triplet)

leading to
triplet =  [0, 0, 16]

and this seemed to work.
Note added: Not sure why, but trying this today and the code now seems to work without the change.
For completeness I ran the programme using the following
   sys version 3.11.9 (tags/v3.11.9:de54cf5, Apr  2 2024, 10:12:12) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
   python version 3.11.9
   numpy version 2.0.0
   scipy version 1.14.0

